# RewriteCond and RewriteRule newbie

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm taking over a website for a client that is running on a custom built CMS (that I didn't write).  I don't mess with .htaccess files usually because a lot of the hosting I do is on IIS, or I used WordPress as a CMS and don't have to worry about messing with the .htaccess file.  Here's the contents of the file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ framework.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&resource=$1& [L]
```

I get what it's doing (sending all requests through the framework.php file).  The client wants a WordPress blog added to their site.  I'm placing it in a /blog/ folder.  The problem is that because of the rewrite rules and conditions in the .htaccess file whenever I try to go /blog/ the other CMS freaks out because it doesn't like me trying to go there.  My question is how do I write a rule/cond that tells apache to send all requests made to the /blog/ folder to the /blog/ folder, but keep all other requests piped through the framework.php file like it is now?  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Btw, explicit %{QUERY_STRING} in RewriteRule right-hand part should be replaced with QSA flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to tell the main .htaccess file to ignore any `/blog` links by adding a `RewriteCond` to the main rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog(/?)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ framework.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&resource=$1& [L]
```

A `/blog` link won't be sent to framework.php, and should serve from the /blog directory normally.  The Wordpress .htaccess file in that directory will be invoked as it normally would, and should be able to handle Wordpress links from there.

Comment: No problem :) [15 char limit filler]